# Random walks and finiteness of a sum

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$, $S_0 = 0$, denote a random walk, where the i.i.d. increments satisfy $EX = 0$ and $EX^2 \in (0,\infty)$. I want to show that for any $x \geq 0$ $$ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty P(0 \leq S_n \leq x, \min_{0 \leq k \leq n} S_k \geq 0) < \infty.$$

It seems that it is not enough to just consider $\min_k S_k$, as it is well-known that $P( \min_{0 \leq k \leq n} S_k \geq 0 ) $ behaves like $n^{-1/2}$. Any ideas?

Note that in our case $\liminf_n S_n = - \infty$ and $\limsup_n S_n = + \infty$.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what your question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_n$ be the event "$0 \leq S_n \leq x$ and $\min_{0 \leq k \leq n} S_k \geq 0$" appearing in the question.  Then the sum in question can be rewritten as
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} E[\#(n \leq t : A_n)]. $$

Choose $\epsilon > 0$ such that $P(X \leq -\epsilon) = \delta > 0$.  Then if it ever happens that $S_n \leq x$, there is a positive probability that the random walk will dip below 0 in bounded time.  Namely, setting $c = \lfloor x/\epsilon \rfloor + 1$, we have
$$ P(S_{n+c} < 0) \geq P(X_{n+1}, \dots, X_{n+c} < -\epsilon) = \delta^c > 0. $$
It follows that conditional on $A_n$, there is a probability $\geq \delta^c$ that $A_m$ will never occur for $m \geq n+c$.

Now fix some $N \in \mathbb N$ (to avoid worrying about convergence issues), and let $k \in \mathbb N$ vary.  We claim that
$$ P(\#(n \leq N : A_n) \geq k \cdot c) \leq (1 - \delta^c)^k. $$
Proof:  Induct on $k$, with the base case $k = 0$ being trivial.  If $A_n$ has already occurred $k \cdot c$ times, the probability that it will occur at least $c$ more times is at most $1 - \delta^c$.

Since $(1 - \delta^c)^k$ decreases exponentially, we get a constant upper bound on $E[\#(n \leq N : A_n)]$.  This doesn't depend on $N$, so it gives an upper bound on $\lim_{t \to \infty} E[\#(n \leq t : A_n)]$ as well.

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect, and that the true decay rate looks like $n^{-3/2}$ rather than exponential. Indeed, if $x=0$ (i.e, we require to start and end at the origin, and also stay nonnegative) then in the case of the simple random walk, you can compute the exact probability in the $(2n)^{th}$ term of summation to be $$\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n} \cdot 2^{-2n}$$ which by Stirling's formula will have a decay like $n^{-3/2}$. [This is obtained by counting Dyck paths](https://math.mit.edu/~apost/courses/18.204-2016/18.204_Gabriella_Baracchini_final_paper.pdf).

Comment: I believe that the inductive step is where the proof fails. There seems to be some subtlety due to the fact that the path is not required to stay strictly between $0$ and $x$, but can have excursions above $x$. Perhaps I'm mistaken about all this, but you should at least try to give some details since this is not the same type of standard induction argument that you'd see in Markov chain theory.

Comment: @Shalop I don't see the issue.  I'm not making any claims about the probability of any particular $A_n$ (i.e. the terms of the original series), only about the probability that at least $n$ $A_i$'s are true.  In your example, my inductive hypothesis says that conditional on returning to the origin $k$ times, there is a $1/2$ chance that we will go negative before returning again.  In particular, there is a $1/2^k$ chance of returning at least $k$ times (without regard to when) before going negative.

Comment: Having said that, this isn't really my area, and I can easily believe there are standard results that would be more illuminating than my argument.  The $n^{-3/2}$ asymptotic looks reasonable, and would give a nice solution if someone knows how to prove it in general.

Comment: Okay you're absolutely right and this is a clever answer that I failed to initially comprehend. I was wrong for talking about the decay rate of the summands here. In probabilistic language I think this argument is sort of excursion-theoretic. You're getting a kind of inductive bound on the (probability of) the number of consecutive excursions of the random walk from $[0,x]$ to itself. Sorry about that.